# How to start anaconda-navigator with root Privileges ? (Linux)

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

After starting "anaconda-navigator" with a terminal, it ends up with dialogue box prompting that " it can't be run with root privileges.[anaconda-navigator startup error as root.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ClWD.png)

Answer (score 1):

For anaconda-3 run:

```
source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root  
anaconda-navigator
```

Hopefully this will solve everything.

Comment: this answer has no benefit for the exact question asked which is what im facing now, problem isnt runing it, problem is not showing the navigator and prompting an error.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue that you have and after trying the shocking solutions provided i ended up with more errors as you can find in some of my comments there.

**How to Fix this:**

The dialogue box as you and I see it, is a common dialogue in the Linux world, it has only one reason and that is your GUI is logged with a "normal user" but somehow you managed to install the anaconda with superuser(root).
so if possible, head to your login section and login with root user + with GUI activated(only saying this because there's a big Linux world out there)

if this didn't help, re-install it but be careful when uninstalling it as python can mess a lot of things up(its an OS bomb actually).

**How to prevent this:**

1- do not allow Anaconda installation to use any superuser areas like /root

2- try to install it with normal user and with sudo command

**Good luck (the thing we all need with python installers)**

Answer (score 0):

The installation process should be done with the regular user but no root. In my case, the problem appears when I installed with superuser session. I follow [these instructions](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/linux/), installing just with my username (without sudo privileges) and the problem was solved.

Comment: I only use the root account, all of my installation and data is in root account.

Answer (score 0):

In `/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/start.py`:

```
if (MAC or LINUX) and os.environ.get('SUDO_UID', None) is not None:
```